# Image feature vector length calculation

Tags: image, vector

Here is the problem: I have an image 256x256 on which wavelet transform is applied. As a result I get a table 16x64 coefficients (3.066568 3.386725 and so on). Do you have any idea how the feature vector length can be calculated?

Comment: Do you know what a feature vector is?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I'm not sure of the way a feature vector lenght calculates. Do you know how it can be calculated?